# Attaching databases results in error "The server principal is not able to access the database"

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 databases that i want to attach them SQL Server Express.

When I try it with another user account, i recieve login failed error.

This code sets the owner of the databases to current user

```
use [DatabaseName] 
create user[DomainName\\UserName] for login [DomainName\\UserName] 
exec sp_addroleMember 'db_owner','DomainName\\UserName'
```

This works for first database but for second one i receive this error:

> the server principal is not able to access the database

How can this be done programmatically?

Comment: i solved this problem.i have activated guest user for my database.i used a query that i found in sql.this query grant all permissions to 'Guest' user of my database.

Answer (score 0):

You should change database owner

```
exec sp_changedbowner 'yourlogin',NULL
```

and then

```
ALTER DATABASE [Your_DB] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the post is too old. But I wanted to post my answer. Actually I think you are tring to connect the database with a user that doesn't have required permisson level for that database. You need to connect the database with a user who has higher permisson level

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue with SQL Server 2016.

For some reasons I have 2 instances - FIYYYY\CRM and FIYYYY\SQLExpress

By default I did connect to FIYYYY\CRM and I was not able to add the database there (got this error there) but when I connect to the FIYYYY\SQLExpress instance I am able to add this database there.
So in my case this is solved.

fixed